# How to highlight a row in the table corresponding to the point on the Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

The code:

```
var chart = new Chart('graph_data', {
type: 'line',
data: {
    labels: data.labels.labels,
    datasets: dataSets
},
options: {
    responsive: true,
    filler: {
        propagate: true
    },
    tooltips: {
        mode: 'index',
        intersect: false,
        callbacks: {
            title: function(i, val) {
                return attributeLabels[data.labels.type] +': '+ i[0].xLabel;
            },
        },
    },
}});
```

[image]

So how can I handle the mouseover and mouseout events of data points area?
I have tryed to add callback for tooltips section, but it doesn`t looks correct and i can`t remove the css class from a row for mouseout event.

```
tooltips: {
        mode: 'index',
        intersect: false,
        callbacks: {
            title: function(i, val) {
                $('#data-table > tbody > tr').eq(i[0].index).addClass('hover');
                return attributeLabels[data.labels.type] +': '+ i[0].xLabel;
            },
        },
    },
```

Comment: Do you want to highlight the table, when hovering the chart or the other way around?

Comment: @insertusernamehere Ideally, both options. But the question was about highlighting the corresponding line when you hover on the chart.